# Having "running" in the email body does not create a email-to-case

Tags: email2case, support

The email-to-case we set up in or Org was not working for some emails. When I troubleshooted and got down to the issue, found that when there is a keyword 'running' in the body of the email, it does not create a Case.

Has anyone come across this issue?

How can this be raised with Salesforce support?

Comment: check your mail server (ask IT) to see if it is filtering out certain messages before forwarding to the xxx.salesforce.com email services address

Comment: No, I can see the email in the inbox of the SF email, so I believe that's not the issue